# What is large dword?

Tags: assembly, types, x86, ida, dword

What function have *short* and *large* in this code portion? large is same as *long dword*?

```
mov eax, ebx
cmp [ebp+var_1], 0
jz  short loc_413123
call sub_40341C
pop large dword ptr fs:0
add esp, 0Ch
```

Comment: This may sound strange, but it will be easier for us to answer this question if you post a hexadecimal dump of the machine code that corresponds to this disassembly.

Comment: I don't have the hexadecimal dump

Comment: Where did you get this if not from a disassembler?

Comment: Considering a dword, is just that, a dword, I doubt that it is a larger dword.

Comment: @Linuxios I *think* you say "qword" for a 64-bit memory access in Intel syntax?  (I know GAS syntax a lot better)  I'm betting "short" and "large" have something to do with the displacement size.  I don't have an assembler to hand that will accept the OP's code without errors, which is why I asked for hex dumps.

Comment: @Zack: I think you're right. In Intel syntax speak, qword is a 64-bit word, and tword is something ridiculously big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### short

`jz  short loc_413123` merely means that the offset (i.e. distance) for this jump is so small that it fits in a single byte, so this jump has been compiled to two simple bytes:

```
0x74 [1-byte-offset]
```

Had the distance been larger, the compiler would have had to encode the jump differently, which would take up more memory:

```
0x0f 0x84 [4-byte-offset]
```

With `short`, IDA Pro is simply telling you what kind of encoding this jump is using.

### large

`pop large dword ptr fs:0` is IDA's way of bringing to your attention that `fs:0` is a [far pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer): a regular offset (`0`) but with a segment selector (`fs`). I.e. `large` has nothing to do with the width of the *data* (dword), but the *address* (segment+offset). However, `large` doesn't really add any new information, that line simply means `pop dword ptr [fs]` and that might be the disassembly you would get from a different disassembler.

---

You can safely ignore both these keywords when you read the disassembly and they are certainly not necessary when writing your own assembly code.

Comment: So `large` in IDA just means there was a segment override?  All addresses in x86 use a segment base ([Write to address without segment register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52649719)); with no override it's usually DS, or SS for base=E/RBP or E/RSP.  (In mainstream OSes, segment bases are 0 for segments other than FS or GS, and in 64-bit mode the HW enforces that, but logically everything is seg:off).

Comment: From another disassembler, you'd typically get something like `pop dword ptr [fs:0]`.  You'd never get just `fs` with no offset, even if the offset is 0.