# mov eax, large fs:30h

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, ida, mov

I was analyzing some x86 binary and found the following instruction which I can not understand. Can someone please explain me following instruction?

```
mov     eax, large fs:30h
```

I googled this, and it turns out it is some anti-debugging stuff... but that's all I know.

what does `large` means?? And what does `fs:30` means??

I know about segmentation but I don't know when the `fs` register is used. For say `cs:`, `ds:` are implicitly skipped when instruction is referencing code or data. But what is `fs`, and what is `gs`?

Comment: What platform? Are you running on Linux?

Comment: See [What is large dword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14061439) for that part of the question.  The answers here only answer the use of `fs` for thread-local stuff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like it's Windows code, loading the address of the Process Environment Block (PEB), via the Thread Information Block, which can be accessed via the FS segment.

The PEB contains, amongest other things, a flag indicating if the process is being debugged.

MSDN has a page about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Via Thread Environment Block (TEB) _TEB `+0x030 ProcessEnvironmentBlock : Ptr32 _PEB` 
Thread Information Block (TIB) _NT_TIB - first member of TEB `+0x000 NtTib : _NT_TIB`

Comment: Yes, exactly.  fs:[30] + 0xC = PEB_LDR_Data, + 0x0C = InMemoryOrderModuleList of loaded modules.  Then you can explore their exports.