# Write to address without segment register

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, real-mode

I know this code will actually write data to ds:[100h]

```
mov [100h], ax
```

But how can I write to linear address `100H` directly without using any segment register for a segment base?

Comment: afair real mode does not support flat memory addressing, only segmented one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get around segment register; every memory access is relative to some segment register.  If you want to write to an absolute address, first load a segment register with an appropriate segment:

```
        xor cx, cx
        mov es, cx        ; es = 0000
        mov [es:100h], ax ; [0000:0100] = ax
```

To load a linear address larger than 16 bit on an 8086 or 80286 system, try something like this:

```
addr    dd 0x12345        ; the address we want to load from
        ...
        mov bl, [addr]    ; load low part
        xor bh,bh
        mov cx, [addr+1]  ; load high part
        shl cx, 4         ; adjust high part for segment selector
        mov es, cx        ; load segment register
        mov [es:bx], ax   ; store ax
```

Comment: But what if the address is more than 16bits? Such as 0x12345h?

Comment: @Jack If you have a 386 or newer, you can use the approach I outlined with a 32 bit address.  Otherwise, you have to manually decompose your address into segment and offset.  If you like, I can add code for the second case.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. And could you please give me the code for the second case? I want to learn. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack Added an example.

Comment: Your example doesn't ever load from `[addr+2]`, only the low 16 bits of your `dd`, and I don't think your shift count is right.  (You probably want to end up with a 16-bit segment value and a 4-bit offset, so your shifting doesn't look right at all.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think the shift count is correct; after all it's `(segment << 4 + addr)` to compute the offset.  I have fixed the memory address for loading `cx`.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah that works too.  You normalize to a 16-bit offset and a segment value with the low 12 bits all zero.  That works as long as the low 16 bits aren't `0xFFFF`.  If they are, the 16-bit load will `#GP` from exceeding the 64k segment limit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh yes indeed.  I could also normalize to an 8 bit offset and a 12 bit segment, let me do that instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, that unaligned load avoids shifting across boundaries nicely, and linear addresses can only be 20 bits, so they fit in 3 bytes.  `xor bx,bx` / `mov bl, [addr]` would be more efficient on some CPUs.

Comment: @fuz I have another problem, now I can write data to 0x12345 by your approach. I can't write data above 0xa0000 although I can read data from these address which confuses me. Is it because it is UMA? And if it is, I want to know that does it only exist on 8086,8088,80186 not 80286 or later x86 CPU? Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Yes, everything above `0xA0000` is not backed by RAM but rather used for ROM and various devices.  For example, the area from `0xA0000` to `0xAFFFF` is used by the video card.  Refer to [this article](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_\(x86\)) for details.

Comment: @fuz Ok, I got it.